# Different behavior of FORMAT function, SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to convert Date to PersianDate, So I'm using `Format` function.
It's OK at local and my `Windows 10`:

```sql
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = '2022-03-16'
SELECT FORMAT(@datetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'fa') -- 1400-12-25
```

But in our server with `Windows Server 2012 R2`, above query return `2022-03-16` and it ignores the culture `fa`!

What's wrong ?

Comment: I suspect that your host doesn't support the culture. According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c) the `fa` culture was added in "Release 7", which was  in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, and is supported in all later versions. I, however, have an old SQL Server 2012 host on Windows Server 2012R2 and i can replicate the problem. This implies that either it might not be shipped with the OS (and needs installing) or the documentation is wrong.

Comment: Have you installed the language (Persian) onto the host that SQL Server is located on?

Comment: @Larnu, No. I didn't install anything to local SQL Server, but it's correct!

Comment: Finally what is the solution?! did you fix it?

Comment: `Windows Server 2012 R2` doesn't support `FORMAT`, I used a function to convert DateTime to Persian DateTime